# hide select value when user form on load

Tags: jquery

I have a form, when user select the first selection, the second selection will activate and display all related list and when user select the second selection and the third selection will activate. 
it works fine but one thing i want it to display blank or hide all the value of "select" when the form first load.

jquery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#region").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $("#city option").hide();
    $("#city").val("");
    $("#city option[value='" + val + "']").show();
    $("#city").change();
  });

  $("#city").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).find(":selected").prop("id");
    $("#brgy option").hide();
    $("#brgy").val("");
    $("#brgy option[value='" + val + "']").show();
  });

});
</script>
```

html

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>SELECT YOUR THE REGION
  <select type="text" value="" id="region">
    <option value="">Please Select Your Region</option>
    <option value="CompostelaValey">CompostelaValey</option>
    <option value="DavaoOriental">DavaoOriental</option>
  </select>
</p><br><br>

<p>SELECT YOUR THE CITY
  <select type="text" name="city" id="city">
    <option value="">Please Select City/Municipality</option>

    <option value="DavaoOriental" id="Baganga">Baganga</option>
    <option value="CompostelaValey" id="Maragusan">Maragusan</option>
    <option value="DavaoOriental" id="MatiCity">MatiCity</option>
  </select>
</p><br><br>

<p>SELECT YOUR THE BARANGAY
  <select type="text" id="brgy">
    <option value="">Please Select Your Barangay</option>
    <option value="Baganga">Baculin</option>
    <option value="Baganga">Batawan</option>
    <option value="Baganga">Batiano</option>
    <option value="Baganga">Binondo</option>
    <option value="Baganga">Bobonao</option>
    <option value="Baganga">Campawan</option>
    <option value="Baganga">Central</option>
    <option value="Baganga">Dapnan</option>
    <option value="Baganga">Kinablangan</option>
    <option value="Baganga">Lambajon</option>
    <option value="Baganga">Lucod</option>
    <option value="Baganga">Mahan-ub</option>
    <option value="Baganga">Mikit</option>
    <option value="MatiCity">Central</option>
    <option value="MatiCity">Badas</option>
    <option value="MatiCity">Matiao</option>
    <option value="Maragusan">kalapagan</option>
  </select>
</p><br><br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You hide all options when the form first load by insert 2 lines into first of `$(document).ready`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#city option").hide();
     $("#brgy option").hide();
     ...
});
```

This is a demo : https://codepen.io/phuongnm153/pen/BXRxPa

Answer (score 0):

just make the other two select fields disabled and make them enabled on change function.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>SELECT YOUR THE REGION
  <select type="text" value="" id="region">
    <option value="">Please Select Your Region</option>
    <option value="CompostelaValey">CompostelaValey</option>
    <option value="DavaoOriental">DavaoOriental</option>
  </select>
</p><br><br>

<p>SELECT YOUR THE CITY
  <select type="text" name="city" id="city" disabled="true">
    <option value="">Please Select City/Municipality</option>

    <option value="DavaoOriental" id="Baganga">Baganga</option>
    <option value="CompostelaValey" id="Maragusan">Maragusan</option>
    <option value="DavaoOriental" id="MatiCity">MatiCity</option>
  </select>
</p><br><br>

<p>SELECT YOUR THE BARANGAY
  <select type="text" id="brgy" disabled="true">
    <option value="">Please Select Your Barangay</option>
    <option value="Baganga">Baculin</option>
    <option value="Baganga">Batawan</option>
    <option value="Baganga">Batiano</option>
    <option value="Baganga">Binondo</option>
    <option value="Baganga">Bobonao</option>
    <option value="Baganga">Campawan</option>
    <option value="Baganga">Central</option>
    <option value="Baganga">Dapnan</option>
    <option value="Baganga">Kinablangan</option>
    <option value="Baganga">Lambajon</option>
    <option value="Baganga">Lucod</option>
    <option value="Baganga">Mahan-ub</option>
    <option value="Baganga">Mikit</option>
    <option value="MatiCity">Central</option>
    <option value="MatiCity">Badas</option>
    <option value="MatiCity">Matiao</option>
    <option value="Maragusan">kalapagan</option>
  </select>
</p><br><br>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#region").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $("#city").attr("disabled",false);
   });

  $("#city").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).find(":selected").prop("id");
    $("#brgy ").attr("disabled",false);
  });

});
</script>
```

this will help with ur requirment

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you need

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#region").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if(val)
     $(".city-wrapper").show();
    else
     $(".city-wrapper").hide();
      
    $("#city option").hide();
    $("#city").val("");
    $("#city option[value='" + val + "']").show();
    $("#city").change();
  });

  $("#city").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).find(":selected").prop("id");
    if(val)
     $(".barangay-wrapper").show();
    else
     $(".barangay-wrapper").hide();
      
    $("#brgy option").hide();
    $("#brgy").val("");
    $("#brgy option[value='" + val + "']").show();
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

.city-wrapper,
.barangay-wrapper {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>SELECT YOUR THE REGION
  <select type="text" value="" id="region">
    <option value="">Please Select Your Region</option>
    <option value="CompostelaValey">CompostelaValey</option>
    <option value="DavaoOriental">DavaoOriental</option>
  </select>
</p><br><br>

<p class='city-wrapper'>SELECT YOUR THE CITY
  <select type="text" name="city" id="city">
    <option value="">Please Select City/Municipality</option>

    <option value="DavaoOriental" id="Baganga">Baganga</option>
    <option value="CompostelaValey" id="Maragusan">Maragusan</option>
    <option value="DavaoOriental" id="MatiCity">MatiCity</option>
  </select>
</p><br><br>

<p class='barangay-wrapper'>SELECT YOUR THE BARANGAY
  <select type="text" id="brgy">
    <option value="">Please Select Your Barangay</option>
    <option value="Baganga">Baculin</option>
    <option value="Baganga">Batawan</option>
    <option value="Baganga">Batiano</option>
    <option value="Baganga">Binondo</option>
    <option value="Baganga">Bobonao</option>
    <option value="Baganga">Campawan</option>
    <option value="Baganga">Central</option>
    <option value="Baganga">Dapnan</option>
    <option value="Baganga">Kinablangan</option>
    <option value="Baganga">Lambajon</option>
    <option value="Baganga">Lucod</option>
    <option value="Baganga">Mahan-ub</option>
    <option value="Baganga">Mikit</option>
    <option value="MatiCity">Central</option>
    <option value="MatiCity">Badas</option>
    <option value="MatiCity">Matiao</option>
    <option value="Maragusan">kalapagan</option>
  </select>
</p><br><br>
```